# How to make an image point to a button (I have multiple versions of it, each pointing to a specific button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For each button that the user hovers on, the image should change with one which points to that button. (I have 14 versions of that image, each pointing lower)

How would this be done with jQuery? Taking the mouse X and Y or using .hover and showing/hiding specific classes? (I think .hover would work better).

It works as expected with .hover() but I can't really seem to make the image stay in the center of its .
I tried many techniques from the internet, but none of them worked.
Screenshot with it not being centered:
[image: click]
Code:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; /*setam textul sa fie optimzat pentru o lizbilitate mai buna, in detrimentul vitezei de incarcare si a preciziei geometrice*/
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    animation-name: tranzitie-inceput;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

#container-mate {
    background: #e6e7d0 url('../img/bg-mate.png');
}

/*HEADER-UL PAGINII*/

#meniu-mate {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

.mate-sus {
    height: 10rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec7bc, #63b4b3 15%, #429ba8);
}

.mate-sus-nerd {
    float: right;
    width: 9%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 65px;
}

.citat-mate-sus {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

.nav-bar-pagina-mate {
    height: 3rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bddc5 15%, #34bab8);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

    .nav-bar-pagina-mate > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

        .nav-bar-pagina-mate > ul > li {
            display: inline;
        }

            .nav-bar-pagina-mate > ul > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                font-style: italic;
            }

/*CONTINUTUL PAGINII*/

#cursuri-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.cursuri-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.selectie-clasa-mate-cursuri,
.selectie-clasa-mate-exercitii, 
.selectie-clasa-mate-quiz {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.cifre-clasa {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.home-mate {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   margin-left: 2rem;
   font-size: 2rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   transition: 1s;
}

.back-mate {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 1s;
}

.back-mate:hover {
        color: #429ba8;
}

.home-mate:hover {
        color: #429ba8;
}

.comutare-mate {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 1s;
}

.comutare-mate:hover {
        color: #429ba8;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul > li {
        opacity: 0;
        margin: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
}

.cifre-clasa > ul > li > a > img {
        width: 85%;
}

.cifre {
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.fa-book {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#exercitii-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.exercitii-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

#quiz-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.quiz-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.fa-question {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.fa-lightbulb {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

#variante-mate {
    height: 12rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.variante-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

/*FOOTER*/

.mate-jos {
    background-color: #28494e;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    height: 12.2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.mate-jos-text {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

#contact-footer {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6rem;
}

#contact-footer i {
        font-size: 5rem;
        padding: 0 3.6rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.footer-social {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14%;
    right: 5%;
}

.logo-mateinfo {
    float: left;
    width: 7.5%;
    left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

#variante-bacalaureat-mate-container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

#variante-bacalaureat-mate-centru {
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Roboto Condensed';
    margin-top: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.semestrul1-variante-bacalaureat-mate {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #499fab, #86bfc7 20%, #abd3d8 50%, #fff);
    width: 95%;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.variante-bacalaureat-mate-lista {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

    .variante-bacalaureat-mate-lista > li {
        height: 4rem;
        line-height: 4rem;
        max-width: 250px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #429ba8;
        margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }

.variante-bacalaureat-mate-1:hover,
.variante-bacalaureat-mate-2:hover,
.variante-bacalaureat-mate-3:hover {
    color: #7ec7bc;
    transition: 0.25s;
    variante-bacalaureator: pointer;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-1,
.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-2,
.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-3 {
    float: right;
    color: #000;
    max-width: 1150px;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.vbac1
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.header-mate-variante-bacalaureat-1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-1 > p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-2 {
    display: none;
}

.header-mate-variante-bacalaureat-2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-2 > p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-3 {
    display: none;
}

.header-mate-variante-bacalaureat-3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-3 > p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>variante-bacalaureat Mate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container-mate">
        <section id="variante-bacalaureat-mate-container">
            <header class="mate-sus">
                <img src="img/mate nerd.png" class="mate-sus-nerd" />
                <h1 class="citat-mate-sus">Egalitatea nu exista decat in matematica.</h1>
            </header>
            <nav class="nav-bar-pagina-mate">
                <a href="index.html" class="home-mate"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
                <a href="pagina-mate.html" class="back-mate"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
                <a href="pagina-info.html" class="comutare-mate">COMUTA PORTAL</a>
            </nav>
            <article id="variante-bacalaureat-mate-centru">
                <h1 class="semestrul1-variante-bacalaureat-mate">variante-bacalaureat - clasa a IX-a</h1>
                <ul class="variante-bacalaureat-mate-lista">
                    <li class="variante-bacalaureat-mate-1">Varianta 1</li>
                    <li class="variante-bacalaureat-mate-2">Varianta 2</li>
                    <li class="variante-bacalaureat-mate-3">Varianta 3</li>
                    <li>Varianta 4</li>
                    <li>Varianta 5</li>
                    <li>Varianta 6</li>
                    <li>Varianta 7</li>
                    <li>Varianta 8</li>
                    <li>Varianta 9</li>
                    <li>Varianta 10</li>
                    <li>Varianta 11</li>
                    <li>Varianta 12</li>
                    <li>Varianta 13</li>
                    <li>Varianta 14</li>    
                </ul>
                <aside class="fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-1">
                    <img src="img/vbac (1).png" class="vbac1" />
                </aside>
                <aside class="fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-2">
                    <img src="img/vbac (2).png" class="vbac2" />
                </aside>
                <aside class="fereastra-mate-variante-bacalaureat-3">
                    <img src="img/vbac (3).png" class="vbac3" />
                </aside>
            </article>
            <footer class="mate-jos">
                <div id="contact-footer">
                    <img src="img/logo web .png" class="logo-mateinfo" />
                    <div class="footer-social">
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>
                        <h6 class="mate-jos-text">© 2018 - Octavian Niculescu (cod), Cezar Stoica (design) pentru INFOEducatie.ro</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </footer>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

I also uploaded it on my website so you can see it:
http://octaniculescu.com/mateinfo/variante-mate.html
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in plain CSS with one single image which will be much more efficient than loading 14 different images.

What I would do would be to use the `:hover` CSS state in combination with `transform(rotates XXdeg)`. This way you just need to assign a number of degrees for the image to rotate when hovering each button.

Check this approach here: https://codepen.io/guillermo-carone/pen/KRBprd

Comment: Got it. Now how can I center the image? I tried multiple ways, position: absolute on the image and relative on the container, margin 0 auto, table but I can't seem to find a way to make it.

Comment: I figured it on my own. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @AndreiDaniel I see you are still using the 14 images approach. Check out the codepen I just added to my answer

Comment: Yeah, I didn't change it because rn I'm too tired. I worked a lot on these pages in the last 3-4 days and I can't anymore. Thanks a lot for your codepen though.